# Get average to closest whole number

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, linq-to-sql

I have two tables

Video

Id,
VideoName,
VideoUrl

Ratings

Id,
VideoId,
CommentDesc,
Rating (**decimal type**)

Multiple users can submit ratings for 1 video multiple times. Each individual's rating is stored in the rating column and can submit a rating including halves i.e. 1.5, 2.5

On my webpage I have a drop-down where the user can select the average rating (the values are 1-5) and will display all the videos with that average rating.

I can get the average using Linq to SQL using something like

```
return myDataCtx.Ratings.Average(i => i.Rating));
```

But if a user selects a whole number between 1-5 from a drop-down how could I round the rating column to the nearest whole number?

Comment: You can use Math.Floor or Match.Ceiling to get the closet highest or lowest number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the nearest number do like this.

```
decimal d = 1.75M;
var ceiling = Math.Ceiling(d);
var floor = Math.Floor(d);

var closest = ceiling - d < d - floor ? ceiling : floor;
```

`x.5` should have to be taken care of separately .

You can also use `Math.Round()`